# C4700 Error and an issue on calling functions

Tags: c++

I have been assigned a project that I am having trouble figuring out the issue. The project is :
"The main() function, which shall ask for input from the user to compute the following: SumProductDifference and Power. There should be a well designed user interface. A void function called SumProductDifference(int,int,int&,int&,int&) that computer the sum, product, and difference of two input arguments, and passes the sum, product and difference by-reference. A value returning function called Power(int a, int b) that computes a raised to the b power. Design and implement your own power function using an iterative control structure, or even recursion. Do no simply write a wrapper around the C++ function called pow(). There should be a user loop and a menu so that the user can select either SumProductDifference, Power, or Quit. The menu should also provide options of allowing the user to set and change the values of the two input integers.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

  using namespace std;

  void SumProductDifference(int, int, int&, int&, int&);
  int Power(int a, int b);
  bool GoAgain();

    int main() {
        int a, b;
        int choice;
        int sum, product, difference;
        do
        {
            cout << "================================================" << endl;
            cout << "=====Welcome to AB Calculator 2016 Edition======" << endl;
            cout << "==== 1 - SumProductDifference Function    ======" << endl;
            cout << "==== 2 - Power of Function                ======" << endl;
            cout << "==== 3 - Quit                             ======" << endl;
            cout << "= Make A Selection:                       ======" << endl;
            cout << "================================================" << endl;
            cin >> choice;

            switch (choice) {
            case '1': SumProductDifference(a, b, sum, product, difference);
                break;
            case '2': Power(a, b);
                break;
            case '3':
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            return 0;   

        } while (choice != 3);
        return 0;

    }

    bool GoAgain() {
        char answer;

        cout << "would you like to go again (y/n) ==> ";
        cin >> answer;

        return answer == 'y';
    }

    void SumProductDifference(int a, int b, int& s, int& p, int& d) {


        cout << "Enter two integers: ";
        cin >> a, b;

        s = a + b;
        p = a * b;
        d = a - b;

        cout << "The sum of " << a << " + " << b << " = " << s << endl;
        cout << "The product of " << a << " * " << b << " = " << p << endl;
        cout << "The difference of " << a << " - " << b << " = " << d << endl;


    }

    int Power(int a, int b) {
        int total = 1;
        int i;
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> a;

        cout << "Raise this integer to the power of: ";
        cin >> b;

        for ( i = 1; i < b; i++) {
            total = total *b;
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please describe the problem you are having with this code?  If you have compiler errors please include the exact error message.

Comment: `cin >> a, b;` I'm 99% sure this does not do what you think it does. ([C4700 is using a variable without initializing it first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axhfhh6x.aspx))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to reduce your code to the [mcve] that demonstrates the problem and to incorporate the exact errors you get from compiling that example (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: The issue I am having is I am using the switch case to create a menu system where the user chooses SumProductDifference it will go to case '1' and then display the outpuit. My problem is when I chose '1' it will just end the program.

Answer (score -1):

Declaring `int choice;` but in the switch - `case '1'`?
You are reading `int` but comparing it to a char literal.
Either change `int choice;` --> `char choice;` or `case '1'` --> `case 1:`

Read about fundamental types in C/C++.
Char is just a 8bit integer, which we conveniently choose to represent a character (with the agreement of the compiler).

Also you are not reading correctly multiple values from std::cin:  `cin >> a, b;` and several other errors.

Learn to research correctly. Consult [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com) before you ask SO.